# Texture painting freeze lag

Tags: texturing

I've started to learn texture painting in blender today, and unfortunately i'm coming across some type of issue.  here's an example of what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyMxo.jpg

It looks like some kind of lag, but i've never had any slowdown problems in blender.  The texture size is 2014, but this happens with any texture size or brush settings.  I've tried multiple Blender versions and they all give me the same issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

just some more info: i have latest gpu drivers, using 1080, and use various other programs without any issues.  so i'm not sure what the cause of this problem is